# Building software for Linux generated using multistrap

Tags: debian, arm, cross-compilation

I am working on an embedded device with ARM CPU and Debian Jessie constructed using multistrap. It seems I need to install a slightly patched version of ModemManager into that system and what I am asking for is any guidance on how to do that.

What I've tried so far is chrooting into the rootfs created by multistrap, downloading the source code of ModemManager using apt-get and building it chrooted. So far, I haven't even got the configure script to pass due to dependencies I can't get satisfied.

Patching is needed in order to solve the known problem of ModemManager that it may confuse hardware by scanning serial ports for modems. There is a way to work around that by blacklisting devices via udev rules, but in this case the serial port is part of the tty sub-system, for which blacklisting is not supported. I have check that in ModemManager's source code.

I am also very open for easier ways to solve this if there are such, but I haven't noticed them so far.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this concrete question is old, adding a modified version of some software to a multistrap-generated debian rootfs is a common problem when using multistrap.

I would not mix cross-compilation with multistrap, because compiling software in the chrootfs generated by multistrap is too laborious.

Instead, I would compile the modified software somewhere where doing so is easy. You may already have a cross-compilation environment for your target ARM architecture, but if not, the easiest method today IMO (and also in 2016) is to use a single-board Linux/ARM computer like the Raspberry Pi with the desired target OS, install the required build tools there and compile your modified software there. No need to set up cross-compilation, because this is using native compilation. When compiled, copy the created binary over to your multistrap environment on your PC.

Run multistrap normally and after it has executed and you have configured all packages in the chroot, just copy the modified binary into the rootfs before using the rootfs on the target hardware.

"Binary" here may mean just the compiled executable, but it can also mean a custom .deb package (that you install with dpkg in the chroot at the end instead of just copying). The latter can provide more protection of your modification because you can then also modify the .deb version number so that your modification will not be reverted later by an `apt update; apt upgrade` if your embedded system can retrieve software updates while running.